# How can I change CSS depending on ajax result?

Tags: jsf

I have a button that submit ajax request:

```
<h:commandButton>
  <f:ajax listener="..." onevent=".." onerror="" render="panel1" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGrid id="panel1" styleClass="${bean.style}> ....
```

I can change CSS if ajax is successful by changing bean.style, but I also wanna change when ajax is sent and when ajax failed. For example, I wanna change the style to `.panel-inprogress` when user clicks the button, `.panel-failed` when failed.

I understand I can do it in JavaScript such as in onevent and onerror attribute my code, but I wanna know if there is a "JSF" way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `<f:ajax>`'s attributes and Javascript is the JSF way in this case.

It wouldn't make much sense to start another Ajax request e.g. to inform the bean that the first ajax request is in progress. It's always delayed and nonsense overhead.

Changes based on the **status** of a running Ajax request (and not it's content) can and should be handled on client-side.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that jsf handles errors using the onerror attribute. There is no mention of a jsf specific way of doing this. I don't believe you have any other choice. I'm sure you've already read this, but here is the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkdcb.html) anyway.